# How to plot object to charts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, chart.js

In the past I have plotted json objects inside an array but I'm wondering how I can plot these array of objects inside an array. I think I'm writing this correctly or it might be starring me in the face. Trying to plot using charts.js Thank you in advance for any helpful suggestions.

OBJECT Example:

{
    "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND": [{
        "LeadSource": "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-06-21",
        "NumLeads": "4"
    },  {
        "LeadSource": "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-07-26",
        "NumLeads": "26"
    }, {
        "LeadSource": "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-07-27",
        "NumLeads": "28"
    }, {
        "LeadSource": "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-07-28",
        "NumLeads": "36"
    }, {
        "LeadSource": "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-07-29",
        "NumLeads": "27"
    }, {
        "LeadSource": "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-07-30",
        "NumLeads": "29"
    }, {
        "LeadSource": "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-07-31",
        "NumLeads": "21"
    }, {
        "LeadSource": "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-08-01",
        "NumLeads": "38"
    }, {
        "LeadSource": "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-08-02",
        "NumLeads": "26"
    }, {
        "LeadSource": "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-08-03",
        "NumLeads": "27"
    }, {
        "LeadSource": "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-08-04",
        "NumLeads": "19"
    }, {
        "LeadSource": "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-08-05",
        "NumLeads": "24"
    }, {
        "LeadSource": "SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-08-06",
        "NumLeads": "17"
    }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a bar chart like this. I export your JSON data [here](https://api.myjson.com/bins/fadwx) and make an ajax request to fetch the data and using it in charts.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  var dataset = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'SOCIAL MEDIA OUTBOUND',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 149, 255, 0.70)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 149, 255, 0.75)',
        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 149, 255, 1)',
        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 149, 255, 1)',
        data: []
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }

  var getData = function(chartdata) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/fadwx',
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        data.forEach((el, i) => {
          chartdata.data.labels.push(el.CreatedDate);
          chartdata.data.datasets[0].data.push(el.NumLeads);
        });
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, chartdata);

      }
    });
  };
  getData(dataset);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you so much!!!  Works great! I have another quick related question. I can also post in a new post as well.  I have done a group by on a json object since I was needing to make a multi-line graph for each lead source. Here's my json object:

Comment: Here's my json object link: https://codepen.io/edwardgnt/post/json-object

Comment: Here's my JSON object group code: codepen.io/edwardgnt/post/json-object-groupby

Comment: welcome. I don't get your new question. you can open a  new question with some elaboration. moreover, If this answer is correct for the current question, you can make it accepted. It will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, sounds good. I'll make another post. I greatly appreciate your time and code. Accepted

Comment: you can provide the link as I can try that

Comment: Here's the link. Thanks again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399623/plot-a-multi-line-graph-from-grouped-json-object-using-charts-js